# No match for operators error

Tags: c++

I just started to learn C++ 2 days ago. I am just learning the basic syntax now. I just learned if statements, and i was trying to practice them. My problem is that at the "if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)" and "if(temp >= 75)" parts of the code, I get the error no match for 'operator' error. I tried looking this up. people with similar problems are using code that i simply cannot follow. I tried implementing their solutions, but i get even more error messages.If someone could please help, i would appreciate it, because i don't know anyone in real like that knows C++ or even anyone that codes. Thanks in advance.Here is the code. Sorry if its messy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Get seed color
    string seedColor = "";
    cout << "Enter seed color (Red or Blue): \n";
    cin >> seedColor;
    //Get Temperature
    string temp = "";
    cout << "Enter the temperature (F): \n";
    cin >> temp;
    //Get soil moisture
    string soilMoisture = "";
    cout <<"Enter the soil moisture (wet or dry): \n";
    cin >> soilMoisture;
    //if red seed
    if(seedColor == "red")
    {
        //if temp is >= 75
        if(temp >= 75)
        {
            //if soil is wet
            if(soilMoisture == "wet")
            {
                //get sunflower
                cout << "A sunflower grew!";
            }

            //if soil is dry
            else
            {
                //get dandelion
                cout << "A dandelion grew!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
        //otherwise

            //get mushroom
            cout << "A mushroom grew!";
        }
    }
    //if blue seed
    if(seedColor == "blue")
    {
        //if temp is between 60 and 70
        if(temp >= 60 && temp <= 70)

        {
            //if soil is wet
        if(soilMoisture == "wet")
        {
            //get dandelion
            cout << "You grew a dandelion!";
        }
        else
        {
            //if soil is dry
            cout << "You grew a sunflower!";
                //get sunflower
        }
        }
        else
        {
        //Otherwise
            cout<< "You grew a mushroom!";
            //Mushroom
        }
```

}
}

Comment: Could you post the actual error you are seeing?

Comment: You can't compare an `std::string` and an `int`. You'll have to convert `temp` into some numerical type.

Comment: I think you meant to make temp an int but instead you made it a string.

Answer (score 2):

This line in your code causes the error:

> ```
> if(temp >= 75)
> ```

`temp` is of type `std::string` and 75 is considered a `int` value. The compiler is right, there's no intrinsic operator

```
bool operator>=(const std::string&,int);
```

declared.

---

You probably want to change your definition of the `temp` variable to

```
int temp = 0;
```

or

```
double temp = 0.0;
```

---

Also you had some small formatting problems. See the [<kbd>fixed code</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/585e36e09aa89f9d).

Comment: If you are going to suggest using a floating point data type then you should also make them aware that [floating point math is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implicitly compare a `std::string` with an `int`, if you keep `temp` as an `int` then use `std::stoi(temp)` to convert it to an `int` and store this value somewhere. Or if you change it to a `double` as the other answer suggests then use `std::stod(temp)` to convert to a floating point number. E.g:

```
std::string temp_str = "";
std::cin >> temp_str;
int temp = std::stoi(temp_str);
// then do comparions/arithmetic with temp
```